# Triggering an alert dialog from AlarmManager (Android)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

(I know I can just use the built-in alarm clock app but I'm a **noob** and I want to learn to do this myself...)

I want to write a reminder app where I can set a time for it pop up a dialog to remind me of something important.  (I want something annoying that I have to dismiss hence a dialog with a message, not just a Notification beep.)   I can pick a time with the TimePicker and execute a service - that's easy.   But now what?

I've read you shouldn't (or can't) launch an AlertDialog from a service.  Should I bind an Activity to the service and launch an AlertDialog from there?   What's best practice?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you have described is ok. On alarm you can launch the activity and it will show an alert dialog.

Yes, you definitely can't show an AlertDialog from service, because service doesn't have anything connected to user interface.